# javascript regex matching a pattern (with conflict)

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose the following string:

`^[message] [site](http://example.com)`

Now, I need a regex that extracts "site" and "http://example.com". I've come up with the following regex:

`/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm`

But this does not exclude `[message]` from the regex result, returning `message] [site` instead of `site`.

I've tried several other possible regex expressions but just can make it to the right one.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\[([^\]]*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm` ?

Comment: It doesn't macht anything @anishsane

Comment: I had tested it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RsgdP1/1). It sill works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to match on the contents within the brackets or parentheses, try and find any character that isn't the end character (`[^\]]` and `[^)]`), also `*?` could be replaced with `+`:

```
/\[([^\]]*?)\]\(([^)]*?)\)/gm
```

Example: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UgGsWh/1)

```js
let str = '^[message] [site](http://example.com)'
let re = /\[([^\]]*?)\]\(([^)]*?)\)/gm

let matches = str.match(re)
console.log( RegExp.$1 )
console.log( RegExp.$2 )
```

Comment: @"also *? could be replaced with +": `*?` and `+` are different. [`*?` is non-greedy match](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/non-greedy-perl-regex.html). `+` is one-or-more match. `x+` is equivalent to `xx*`. Probably you mixed regex and wildcards.

Comment: Nope, no mix up, what he’s trying to achieve he can use `+` in place of the `*?`. You’ll notice that it would be + for any non-bracket character. The whole point of this is to capture text and the non-bracket-char match makes the two patterns mostly equivalent

Answer (score 0):

if that space is always there:

```
/\s\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your string, and using javascript, `\^\[.*?\]\s\[(.*)\]\((.*?)\)/gm` should suffice so long as you **always extract group1, group2**, but **ignore group0**... try the below code;

```
// set up a test string with multiple matches
var text = "daska ^[message] [site](site.com) fjhdfgk fafug ^[message2] [site2](site2.com) fgsadkfgaskf akfkakf";

// collect all matching groups globally
// (this creates an array of full matches which we can water down next)
var results = text.match( /\^\[.*?\]\s\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm );
// output: ["^[message] [site](site.com)", "^[message2] [site2](site2.com)"]

// use the full matches to extract the groups we want,
// and then fill an array of matches
results = results.map( function( result ) {
    var match = result.match( /\^\[.*?\]\s\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/ );
    return [ match[1], match[2] ];
});
// output: [["site", "site.com"], ["site2", ["site2.com"]]
```

You should be able to use the output array to do whatever you require :)

Comment: I've tried your regex but it doesn't return any matching

Comment: The regex on it's own is working, as you can see here https://regex101.com/r/dnBEcY/1 , but it's a little difficult to use on it's own, which is why I provided a `results.map(...)` method to sanitise. ~~ However my whole answer is based on the original post, presuming you might have more than one `^[message] [site](site.com)` arrangement in your text. I guess not?

Answer (score 0):

`\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)` Will match `message] [site` in the first capturing group because it will try to match at least as possible until it can match an opening parenthesis.

Instead you could use 2 [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)  first matching `^[message]` and after that match start the capturing groups.

`\^\[[^\]]+]\s+\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GGflU0/1)

**Explanation**

- `\^` match `^`
- `\[[^\]]+]` Match what is between `[]` using a negated character class
- `\s+` Match one or more times a whitespace character
- `\[([^\]]+)\]` Match what is between `[]` in a capturing group using a negated character class *(group 1)*
- `\(([^)]+)\)` Match what is between `()` in a capturing group using a negated character class *(group 2)*

```js
const regex = /\^\[[^\]]+]\s+\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/;
const str = `^[message] [site](http://example.com)`;
let [, group1, group2] = str.match(regex);
console.log(group1);
console.log(group2);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your regex is : `\[(.*?)\]` 
it is matching everything in the outer square bracket`[]` , to fix this you can use
`[^[]*` instead of `(.*?)`, because the bigger outer square bracket`[]` contains `[`, therefore including `^\[` will exclude it from matching.

```
/\[([^\[]*)\]\((.*?)\)/gm
```

[try demo at regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/FgT2D9/1)

Comment: Thank you! It worked great and also you explained perfectly.